# Not a Group by expression error [joining tables]

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

Group by not working when I tried to get maximum of the value column grouped with different subject names & staff names.

The select query inside first brace works fine and I'm getting the desired output from that. But, I'm not able to get maximum value for each staff, subject from that.

```
select  staff_name, subject_name, max(value) from 
(select Staff.staff_name, Subject.subject_name, Mark.value as value 
from ((staff inner join subject on Staff.staff_id=Subject.staff_id)
inner join Mark ON Mark.subject_id=Subject.subject_id) 
group by subject_name);
```

Error is:

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

Comment: All the non-aggregated columns must be in `GROUP BY`.  In this case, you must put `staff_name` in your `GROUP BY` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you have  wrong sequence for nested () 
and you have missed  a not aggregated column in group by

```
select  t.staff_name, t.subject_name, max(t.value) 
from (
    select Staff.staff_name, Subject.subject_name, Mark.value as value 
    from staff 
    inner join subject on Staff.staff_id=Subject.staff_id
    inner join Mark ON Mark.subject_id=Subject.subject_id
) t
group by t.staff_name, t.subject_name;
```

Comment: For that matter, the subquery nesting is unnecessary, unless the query is very different than what the OP actually posted.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need this:

```
select st.staff_name, su.subject_name, max(mk.value) 
from   staff st
       join subject su
            on  su.staff_id = st.staff_id
       join mark mk
            on  mk.subject_id = su.subject_id
group by st.staff_name, su.subject_name
```